# URL not opening in Web view

Tags: android

I am trying to open [this link](http://www.rowseatsplugin.com/development/?wpgc=3NF7QF3W3GTG) which is redirected to another `URL`, in `WebView` . But it's not showing the page.
Code:

```
web.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        web.loadUrl(url);

        return true;
    }
});
```

Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this :

```
    web.setWebViewClient(new myWebClient());
    web.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    web.loadUrl("http://www.technotalkative.com");


   public class myWebClient extends WebViewClient
   {
    @Override
    public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        view.loadUrl(url);
        return true;

    }

    @Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPageFinished(view, url);

        progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
}

// To handle "Back" key press event for WebView to go back to previous screen.
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)
{
    if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) &amp;&amp; web.canGoBack()) {
        web.goBack();
        return true;
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

Comment: Web view dose not refresh each time i load, it holds previous web page data. webview.clearView() not working?

Answer (score 0):

Tried this.

```
web.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                web.loadUrl(url);

                return true;
            }
        });`
web.loadUrl(url);
```

Comment: Yes. i have tried this as well. Its not showing. The problem is that Real URl is redirected to another URL and web view is unable to handle this redirected URL. I have posted real URL which you can try at your end. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

You need to use **"view"** (WebView object) which is parameter of that method.

```
 web.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            view.loadUrl(url);

            return true;
        }
    });
```

Use this is working for me...